# Bar chart in grafana based on 2 number data series

Tags: grafana

I have MySQL table, where I group by value and count number of instances. I receive table, but how to visualize it now in Grafana?

[image]

[image]

```sql
SELECT COUNT(a) AS "counter", a AS "value" FROM app_db.`mytable` GROUP BY a ORDER BY a ASC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: You can use Transformation *Convert field type* to convert one of your fields into string. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You @markalex, I need to convert type from number to string using Convert field type:
[image]
And now I can show data as bar chart:
[image]